# Labelling the contours with numbers and then extracting the coordinates of any numbered contour

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I need to label each contour with numbers so that with the help of following code i can extract the coordinates of that particular contour.

**Here is the image:**

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

THRESHOLD = 55
CONTOUR = 55

im = cv2.imread("ceramic.bmp")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,THRESHOLD,255,0)
_th,contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print "Number of contours detected = %d" % len(contours)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,CONTOUR,(1,70,255))
area = cv2.contourArea(contours[CONTOUR])
print (area)
cv2.imshow("Contours",im)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
coords = np.array2string(contours[CONTOUR])
open("contour_%d.txt" % CONTOUR, "w").write(coords)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by labeling them?

Comment: What do you think `contours` contains if not the coordinates of each contour?

Comment: I want  to assign them a number for representation so that if I am having a thousand of contours in an image, I can easily see and find contour specific coordinates.

Comment: @ChanchalDixit So you want each contour to have a unique number and store the corresponding coordinates of that contour as well?

Comment: @JeruLuke yes, exactly I want the same as said by you

Comment: @Chanchal you can iterate through each contour and give it a number. For each of those contours save their corresponding coordinates in a dictionary

Comment: @ChanchalDixit I just modified your code. See how it works!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to mention in your code:

1. Firstly, when you want to find contours the shape must be in white. The image provided by you has shapes that are dark. So I had to invert your image and then find the contours.
2. Secondly, you were storing coordinates of only one contour. I have modified your code to store coordinates for each contour in a separate file.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

THRESHOLD = 55

path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/'
im = cv2.imread(path + 'date.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("imgray", imgray)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, THRESHOLD, 255, 0)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

_th, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cv2.bitwise_not(thresh),     cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print "Number of contours detected = %d" % len(contours)

cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (1, 70, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Contours", im)

contour_num = 0 
for i in range(0, len(contours)):
    coords = np.array2string(contours[i])
    contour_num+=1
    open(path + 'contour_%d.txt' %contour_num, "w").write(coords)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Run the code as it is and see the saved files.

Comment: I am getting the following error(cv) bmrl@bmrl-desktop:~/Kartikeya/opencv/IC$ python stackex1.py
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor, file /home/bmrl/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackex1.py", line 8, in <module>
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/bmrl/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor

Comment: You have to change the path to the image then run as it is